# Class loaded multiple times by Weblogic classloder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, classloader

I did activate on JVM level the trace for the classloader and I see DTDDVFactory and DTDDVFactoryImpl loaded twice

Once from the endorsed library

```
[Loaded org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory from /ec/envvar/server/weblogic/u010/home/wlstress/data/EFORMS103_envvar/endorsed_library/xercesImpl.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl from /ec/envvar/server/weblogic/u010/home/wlstress/data/EFORMS103_envvar/endorsed_library/xercesImpl.jar]
```

---

Second time from JDK:

```
[Loaded com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory from /ec/local/weblogic/u000/app/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl from /ec/local/weblogic/u000/app/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

---

Now which of the above DTDDVFactory and DTDDVFactoryImpl will be used by an application deployed on this Weblogic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the logs the classes have different package names therefore the class with the matching FQCN (fully qualified class name) is used.

Comment: However in case they will be the same ? which one is used ? Cause they might be same class different versions...

Comment: @Cris the class with the `ClassLoader` which is the correct one for the current context. This is a little bit more complex to explain.

Comment: Well a web app will want to use this class...there will be the application classloader which will not have this class (cause i do not package it inside) ...however i read this Java Classloader Hierarchy http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html and still not clear which on will be used

Comment: I found the answer :" If a class exists in both the parent and child classloaders, the parent version is loaded"